# D3.js Extending Axis Component Custom Labeling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a gene visualization tool that will display the full nucleotide and amino acid sequence for a gene. As far as I can tell the tickFormat function will not suffice for my situation so I'm extending the d3 axis component to change the display of the ticks and labels.

When zoomed my x-axis should display the amino acid and nucleotide sequences. 3 Nucleotides form an amino acid. So I want to have each nucleotide represent one position on the x-axis, then under each group of 3 nucleotides I want to have the amino acid formed displayed just once.

This is an example of the axis labels ('His' is the amino acid, 'G','G' and 'C' are the nucleotides):
His:327:G
His:328:G
His:329:C

I can select the label but then how can I grab the label's text and split it into two separate text elements?

I'm thinking that all I have to do is clone the text element, strip the His:328 from the original. Then I can change the cloned element's text and fix the y position so it's just beneath the original.

Here is my CustomAxis Code so far:

```
 var customXAxis = (function() {
        var base = d3.svg.axis();

        // Select and apply a style to your tick marks
        var newAxis = function(selection) {
            selection.call(base);
//            selection.selectAll('.tick', this).append('text').text('text');
        };
        // Copy over every method from the base axis 'ticks', 'scale', etc.
        for(var key in base) {
            if (base.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                d3.rebind(newAxis, base, key);
            }
        }

        return newAxis;
    })();
```

I also setup a fiddle here with the complete code (Please note that I plan on cleaning up the code and using the Chart pattern described by Mike Bostock once I get this to work. My focus is on getting this to work right now, not code style.): https://jsfiddle.net/zu51vv8y/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If what is to be displayed as a label is entirely determined by the data, then `.tickFormat()` should suffice. What do you want to do that you can't do with `.tickFormat()`?

Comment: So my axis labels currently look like this: His:327:G His:328:G His:329:C. I want to put the GGC on top and the His under the GGC. As far as I can tell, this can only be accomplished by splitting the text element into 2 and positioning one underneath the other. The tickFormat function can only alter the display, it cannot add new lines.

Comment: Ah, I see. You could do something similar to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) after the labels have been generated.